# If - else doesn't work - where could be mistake

Tags: java, if-statement

world! :)
It is my third programming day (please, be lenient...)
Code was intended to find out whether the sum (when it reaches 1 digit only) of digits of number 123456789 can be divided by 9.
I cannot find how to make second 'else' work - any help and explanation why so would be highly appreciated:

```
package lesson3;

public class Task6 {
    
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n=123456789;
        System.out.println(n);
        do{
            private static int sumDigits(int n)
            int s=sumDigits(n); 
            if (s < 10) ;
            {
                if (s == 9) System.out.println("divides by 9");
                else System.out.println("doesn't divide by 9");
                break;
            }

           else n = s;

        }while (true);

    }
```

Comment: Think about the semicolon you have in `if (s < 10) ;`

Comment: Why not make a `sumDigits(int n)` function inside of the class `Task6`. That would help with some code organization (separating user input from your math).

Comment: You put an extra semicolon. Please mark the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The function, `sumDigits` should return the sum of digits of the parameter, `n`. For this, you can add each digit of `n` to a variable, `sum` initialized with the value, `0`. The value of `x % 10` gives you the last digit of `x`. Every time you add the last digit of `n` to `sum`, divide it by `10` to make it one digit less from the end.
2. You need a loop to pass the sum of digits to `sumDigits` until the sum of digits become a single digit. I suggest you use a `do-while` loop which guarantees its body to be executed at least once.
3. At the end of the loop mentioned in point#2, you will have the sum of digits as a single digit. The final thing that you need to do now is to check if this sum is divisible by `9`.

Note that if `x % y == 0`, then `x` is divisible by `y`.

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 123456789;
        int singleDigitSum = 0;
        int divisibleBy = 9;

        do {
            singleDigitSum = sumDigits(n);
            n = singleDigitSum;
        } while (singleDigitSum > 9);

        if (singleDigitSum % divisibleBy == 0) {
            System.out.println("The single digit sum is divisible by " + divisibleBy);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The single digit sum is divisible by " + divisibleBy);
        }
    }

    private static int sumDigits(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
            sum += n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The single digit sum is divisible by 9
```

**Note:** Java does not allow defining a method/function inside another method/function. You have done this mistake by defining the function, `sumDigits` inside the method, `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
package lesson3;

public class Task6 {
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
int number = 123456789;
int sumOfDigits = sumDigits(number);

if (sumOfDigits%9 == 0) {
System.out.println("divides by 9");
return;
}
System.out.println("doesn't divide by 9");
}

public static int sumDigits(int num)
int sum = 0;
while (num > 0) {
sum = sum + num % 10;
num = num / 10;
}
return sum;
}
```